# Questions solved with alternative solutions; how to handle them?

Tags: discussion, questions

I've had multiple occasions in which I asked a question on Stack Overflow/Super User/etc. where I eventually decided to use a different solution.

How should I handle these questions? Should I reply stating what alternative solution I've used?

Answer (score 4):

This happens to me all the time, too. I either accept the answer that I found *most* helpful, or I post my own solution (if I believe it will be more helpful to future users more than any of the other posts).

Comment: I usually accept the most helpful answer (if it was actually helpful, and not just marginal) and then post my own solution if it was substantially different, often by editing the question.

Comment: Yeah I was just thinking about posting my own alternative solution, and possible motivations why the alternative is better.